# Guake terminal freezing when focus is lost

Tags: guake

I am running into an issue with Guake. I am running cli-visualiser in a Guake terminal, however whenever this terminal loses focus, i.e. viewing a chrome tab over it, the terminal completely freezes, (can't ctrl + c) or anything and I have to reload it. (it is taking the commands though as when I reload it, I can see that my inputs were still being registered, it was just visually frozen)

I don't run into this issue if I have the setting "always on top" checked if this is of any help. If yas have any advice on resolving this it would be great.

If you need me to provide any outputs etc... please ask and I'll be more than happy to get them for you :)

Cheers.